# Calculate width of middle div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs

I am using float:left to have the divs in the same line.  my problem is that the div1 will have a random width.  Div 3 will be always 25 pixels with margin left and right of 1.  and then the middle div needs to fill up the remaining space.

What would be the best way to accomplish this and still be supported in all browsers?

Here is what I tried, but the problem is that the % width wont work because div1 will always change in width.

```
<div class="title-div gradient">
    <div class="title-div-left">
        <p>Service 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="background-line"></div>
        <div class="title-div-right">
            <img src="ArrowUp.png" alt="▲">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.services-wrapper .expansion-wrap .title-div {
  height: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  width: 95.6rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 3.4rem;
  background: #6f1505;
  /* Old browsers */
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6f1505 0%, #340801 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #6f1505), color-stop(100%, #340801));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6f1505 0%, #340801 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6f1505 0%, #340801 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6f1505 0%, #340801 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6f1505 0%, #340801 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6f1505', endColorstr='#340801',GradientType=0 );


.services-wrapper .expansion-wrap .title-div .title-div-left {
  float: left;
}
.services-wrapper .expansion-wrap .title-div .title-div-left p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 1.7rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
}
.services-wrapper .expansion-wrap .title-div .background-line {
  background-image: url("../images/Line.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-position: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.services-wrapper .expansion-wrap .title-div .title-div-right {
  float: left;
  height: 3.5rem !important;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
.services-wrapper .expansion-wrap .title-div .title-div-right img {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: The posted markup doesn't seem to be completed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `overflow: auto` will make the div fill up the remaining space.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aaL8gvhg/

Comment: I have followed your example, but my green bar always goes to the new line.  Here is the example: http://tiu.azularis.com/Services  Any chance you could tell me why?

Comment: Yeah, I should've mentioned that, since `overflow:auto` fills up the remaining space you need to put it after the right div in html. So first left div, then right div and then middle div.